# Android asynchronous UI Updating from service fails

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a very strange problem for updating UI. I have a foreground started bounded service which my main process in background. When I start app,  I like to check if service is already running and change state of a toggle button. For this problem, I bind to my started service when starting app in OnResume() and service sends a value back to my app which shows running status of service and I update UI based on this value. But the problem is that UI is not updated in this situation.

Because this bug is shown in a very complex situation, I have written a sample code that reproduce this problem. Here are these codes (sorry for bad names and missing a lot of error checks, I have quickly written this code just to reproduce problem). I have discussed each code a little as an overview.

**activity_main layout:**

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/ui_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOff="Off State"
    android:textOn="On State"
    android:checked="false" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/start_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"/>
```

**MyTestService.java**

At first, this is my sample foreground started bounded service. As you see, when we start service, we create a foreground service which just runs a small thread that toggles a `mStatus` variable every 10 seconds for 10 times and then stops. Whenever we bind to this service, we use `ResultReceiver` which is sent through binding intent in order to send `mStatus` to app. We also allow rebinding, because app may be closed several times and reopened again.

```
public class MyTestService extends Service {
    private volatile boolean mStatus = false;
    private MyThread mTh = new MyThread();

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mTh.start();

        Intent notintent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notintent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentText("Test").setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setContentTitle("title").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        startForeground(100, notification);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction().equals("checkstatus")) {
            ResultReceiver recv = (ResultReceiver)intent.getParcelableExtra("myrecvextra");
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putBoolean("status", mStatus);
            recv.send(0, data);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction().equals("checkstatus")) {
            ResultReceiver recv = (ResultReceiver)intent.getParcelableExtra("myrecvextra");
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putBoolean("status", mStatus);
            recv.send(0, data);
        }
    }

    public class MyThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    mStatus = !mStatus;
                    Log.i("ASD", String.format("%d", mStatus? 1 : 0));
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
            }

            stopSelf();
        }
    }
}
```

**MyServiceAccessClass.java**

This class is used for accessing service. `start()` starts service, `bind()` and `unbind()` are using for binding and unbinding service. `mRecv` is the `ResultReceiver` which send to service while binding and is used for getting status. When status is received after binding, `ResultReceiver` updates UI via a callback.

```
public class MyServiceAccessClass {
    private MyResultRecv mRecv = new MyResultRecv(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()));
    private OnUpdateRequest mCallback = null;
    private Context mCtx = null;
    private ServiceConnection mCon = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {}
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {}
    };

    public MyServiceAccessClass(Context ctx) {
        mCtx = ctx;
        mCallback = (OnUpdateRequest)ctx;
    }

    public void bind() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, MyTestService.class);
        intent.setAction("checkstatus");
        intent.putExtra("myrecvextra", mRecv);
        mCtx.bindService(intent, mCon, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    public void unbind() {
        mCtx.unbindService(mCon);
    }

    public void start() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, MyTestService.class);
        mCtx.startService(intent);
    }

    private class MyResultRecv extends ResultReceiver {

        public MyResultRecv(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            if (resultCode == 0) {
                mCallback.updateUi(resultData.getBoolean("status"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

This is main class of test app. Start button starts service. and this class binds in `OnResume()` and unbinds in `OnPause()`. If app is run when service is already running and its `mStatus` is `true`, then `updateUi` will be called with `true` value and sets status of toggle button.

```
interface OnUpdateRequest {
    public void updateUi(boolean state);
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnUpdateRequest{
    private MyServiceAccessClass mTest = new MyServiceAccessClass (this);
    private ToggleButton mBtn = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mBtn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.ui_btn);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.start_btn)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTest.start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mTest.bind();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mTest.unbind();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUi(boolean state) {
        mBtn.setChecked(state);
    }
}
```

Ok, now in theory everything is all right. But if you try to use this code, when service is started and `mStatus` is true, toggle button's `setChecked()` will be called with `true` (which is correct till now) but UI will not be updated to show correct text and status. Funny part is that if you run `isChecked` for this toggle button, it will return `true`, but UI shows something else.

Any idea why this happens? Sorry for a lot of codes, this problem occured is this complex situation.

**Update**

I noticed something that I should mention. if I use `isChecked` right after `setCheck`, I get `true` which is correct. But if I use `isChecked` again some time later (for example in another button event handler),  it returns `false` while I have not called `setChecked` anymore. I think this situation is related to my problem but I don't know how this is happened.

In addition, I think this problem is related to updating UI when you are in binding process to a service. because if I try to update app main UI with same `ResultReceiver` when I'm not in binding process, everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem with my code. **It took me a lot of time to solve this problem**, so I post it here for other android developers.

Sending result back from a service is somehow obvious via `ResultReceiver`. But most of examples in internet does not show service rebinding, and **I never found sending result back after rebinding service**.

OK, now what is the problem? look at the following part of code from my service:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null && intent.getAction().equals("checkstatus")) {
        ResultReceiver recv = (ResultReceiver)intent.getParcelableExtra("myrecvextra");
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putBoolean("status", mStatus);
        recv.send(0, data);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null && intent.getAction().equals("checkstatus")) {
        ResultReceiver recv = (ResultReceiver)intent.getParcelableExtra("myrecvextra");
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putBoolean("status", mStatus);
        recv.send(0, data);
    }
}
```

This is a common approach for making a rebinding service, based on simple binding to service that you find in internet. This has been done with returning `true` in `onUnbind()` and using `onRebind()`. But this approach is **completely wrong**.

Why? Because of a strange design in android. In [Service OnRebind()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onRebind(android.content.Intent)), there is a small 18 word comment:

> Note that any extras that were included with the Intent at that point
>   will not be seen here.

Now What this means? It means that extra which carries `ResultReceiver` will not be available on rebinding which in turn means that results will not be sent back after rebinding. But for unknown reason, this code does not make any exception and you even see result back in app while debugging, so it is super ambiguous why this code does not work.

Now what is the solution? Never send `ResultReceiver` when you bind to a service with `bindService()` intent. Even though this is correct for a non-rebinding service, but I highly suggest to avoid it. Send `ResultReceiver` via a separate message to service when `onServiceConnected` is called and then everything works like a piece of cake. Here are my modifications for code:

**MyTestService.java**

```
public static int SERVICE_SET_RECV = 1;
public static String SERVICE_RECV = "SERVICE_RECV";

private Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new MyHandler(this));
private ResultReceiver mRecv = null;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null && intent.getAction().equals("checkstatus")) {
        return mMessenger.getBinder();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    mRecv = null;
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {}

public void setRecv(ResultReceiver recv) { 
    mRecv = recv; 

    // Example to send some result back to app
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putBoolean("status", mStatus);
    mRecv.send(0, data);
}

private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<MyTestService> mService;

    public MyHandler(MyTestService service) {
        mService = new WeakReference<>(service);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        MyTestService service = mService.get();
        Bundle data = msg.getData();

        switch (msg.what) {
            case SERVICE_SET_RECV: {
                ResultReceiver recv = data.getParcelable(SERVICE_RECV);
                service.setRecv(recv);
                break;
            }
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

**MyServiceAccessClass.java**

```
private ServiceConnection mCon = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Messenger messenger = new Messenger(service);

        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putParcelable(MyTestService.SERVICE_RECV, mRecv);
        Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MyTestService.SERVICE_SET_RECV, 0, 0);
        msg.setData(data);

        messenger.send(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {}
};

public void bind() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, MyTestService.class);
    mCtx.bindService(intent, mCon, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

Finding this ridiculous problem took me a lot of time. I wish everyone likes this solution and solves a lot of problems for rebinding a service.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly need to call `View.requestLayout()` or `View.forceLayout()` on the buttons View to refresh the buttons state.

Comment: I tried calling `invalidate()`, but it didn't work. I will try these 2 too.

Comment: neither `requestLayout()` nor `forceLayout()` worked too.

Comment: Can you try to put `runOnUiThread()` around `mCallback.updateUi(resultData.getBoolean("status"));` Just an idea...

Comment: not working. Btw, I made a small update to main question.

Comment: I think your problem of the binding process occures because of this line: `intent.putExtra("myrecvextra", mRecv);` Here you'll gain a copy of this object (because of parcelable). I think the callback will be copied too, so you will update the togglebutton of a copy. Maybe this link can help you: http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android